How to evaluate$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(n\left(n..\left(\int_0^1\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2}\right)^ndx-l_0\right)-l_1..\right)-l_{m}\right)$?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx= \frac{2}{3}$$

I became curious what happens If we do the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx- \frac{2}{3}\right)$$
The numerical methods suggest that this will be $\frac 2 {27}$
what If we took this farther ? $$= \lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(n\left(\int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx- \frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac 2 {27} \right) ?$$
lets define $\displaystyle l_0:= \frac{2}{3}$, $\displaystyle x_{n,0}:=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2}\right)^ndx$, $ \displaystyle l_1:= \frac 2 {27} $, $\displaystyle x_{n,1}:= n\left(\int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx- \frac{2}{3}\right)$
In general $\displaystyle x_{n , m+1}= n (x_{n,m}- l_{m} )$ and $\displaystyle  l_{m}= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_{n,m}$.
Assuming of course that $l_m \in \mathbb{R}$
Is it possible to find a closed form for all $l_m $? and what is $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} l_m$?

Interesting problem ! Not sure that a closed form could be obtained but, numerically the results are interesting.

Denote your integral by $I(n)$. First, we perform the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $
x = {\rm e}^{ - nt} $ to transform the integral into the form
$$
I(n)=n\int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - 2t}  + {\rm e}^{ - t} }}{2}} \right)^n {\rm d}t}  = n\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - n\log \left( {\frac{2}{{{\rm e}^{ - 2t}  + {\rm e}^{ - t} }}} \right)} \right){\rm d}t} .
$$
An application of Laplace's method then yields the asymptotic expansion
$$
I(n) \sim \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{l_m}{n^m } =
\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{{27}}\frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{{81}}\frac{1}{{n^2 }} - \frac{2}{{729}}\frac{1}{{n^3 }} -  \ldots ,
$$
as $n\to+\infty$, where
$$
l_m  = \left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^m }}{{{\rm d}t^m }}\left( {\frac{t}{{\log \left( {\frac{2}{{{\rm e}^{ - 2t}  + {\rm e}^{ - t} }}} \right)}}} \right)^{m + 1} } \right]_{t = 0} = 2\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^m }}{{{\rm d}t^{m } }}\left( {\frac{t}{{3t - \log \cosh t}}} \right)^{m + 1} } \right]_{t = 0} .
$$

@Gary already gave the solution.
I obtained the same terms using
$$ \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{x}+1}{2} \right)^n dx=2 \,\, _2F_1(1,2 n+1;n+1;-1)$$ Computing with illimited arithmetic, we generate a sequence
$$2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{3^{b_n}} \frac 1{n^k}$$ where the very first $a_n$ are
$$\{1,1,1,-1,-55,-19,49\}$$ and the first $b_n$ are $$\{1,3,4,6,8,7,10\}$$ Using @Gary's nice and elegant formula, it seems that the next $a_n$ become quite large (I have not been able to get it).
